# Replacing Annotation image with Character or Number in Titanium Map view

Tags: android, titanium-mobile

I have created Map view using following code

```
var map = Ti.Map.createView({   

    mapType:Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
    regionFit: true,
    animate: true,
    touchEnabled: true,
    userLocation:true,
    region:{

        latitude: 19.076719,
        longitude: 72.878583,
        latitudeDelta:0.5,
        longitudeDelta:0.5
    }   

 });
```

I am creating Annotation using following code

```
var pin = Ti.Map.createAnnotation({

    latitude:19.076719,
    longitude:72.878583,
    title:  "Dronzer",
    image:"pin.png"

});
map.addAnnotation(pin);
```

**Question:** How to replace this image with number "12" to show it on map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few days some how I have found the solution.

1. Create a Label

   ```
     var price = Ti.UI.createLabel({

                   text : "  "+data.price,//Number=12 Input from server
                   color : 'black',
                   font : {fontSize:'15dp',font:"monospace",fontWeight:"bold"},
                   height : '30dp',
                   width : '30dp',
                   left: '50%',     
                   backgroundImage:"red_pin1.png",

               });
   ```
2. Create an ImageView and set its image property as a blob.

   ```
   var anImageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                   image : price.toImage(), //setting label as a blob
                   width : 'auto',
                   height : 'auto',
               });
   ```
3. Create an Annotation and set its image property as blob.

   ```
   var pin = Ti.Map.createAnnotation({

                   myid:data._id,
                   latitude:data.latitude,
                   longitude:data.longitude,
                   title:  data.vendor_name,
                   image:anImageView.toBlob() //setting ImageView as blob

               });
   ```

Comment: **Note:** It is working in SDK version 3.0.0 GA. Will not work in latest SDK.